# Dynamic Get Rank By Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, ranking

I have a result table like:

```
ID  STUDENT_ID  Branch_id   Class_id    Exam_id Subject_id  Numbers     Date
1       653         5           1           1   8               60      2012-01-01
2       653         5           1           1   9               40      2012-01-01
3       653         5           1           1   10              80      2012-01-01
4       653         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
5       653         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
6       653         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       653         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
8       222         5           1           1   8               100     2012-01-01
9       222         5           1           1   9               80      2012-01-01
10      222         5           1           1   10              92      2012-01-01
11      222         5           1           1   11              50      2012-01-01
12      222         5           1           1   12              65      2012-01-01
13      222         5           1           1   13              33      2012-01-01
7       222         5           1           1   15              86      2012-01-01
```

My Desire Result like:

```
Student_ID  Math    English      Science    Total   Rank
1       90  89      88  267  1
2       90  89      88  267  1
3       58  45      98  201      2
```

I want to get student rank by this method:

[Reference Link](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/)

```
SET @rank = 0, @prev_val = NULL;

SELECT rank, correct FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        @rank := IF(@prev_val=correct,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank,
        @prev_val := correct AS correct, uid
    FROM quiz_user 
    ORDER BY correct DESC
)as result WHERE uid=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This query what I need only difference between table structure the author of post assign a rank on correct column and I need to assign rank on numbers SUM(numbers) column after sum all numbers.

Please Help.

Comment: please clearify your question what you want?

Comment: I want to get rank of student if one or more student equal in marks example: Two students get 500 marks out of 500 marks that means both are on first position. so in above query work fine if two are equal in rank only I want to calculate rank on SUM(numbers) instead correct column.

Comment: can you provide schema with this sample data?

Comment: Provide simple data with desired result, please.

Comment: My table data I have provide and in post there is example data exists too. What I provide after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID, Numbers, IF(@marks=(@marks:=Numbers), @auto, @auto:=@auto+1) rank 
FROM (SELECT STUDENT_ID, SUM(Numbers) Numbers
      FROM quiz_user 
      GROUP BY STUDENT_ID 
      ORDER BY Numbers DESC, STUDENT_ID 
     ) AS A, (SELECT @auto:=0, @marks:=0) AS B;
```

Comment: I want to ask another question? for all class rank.

Comment: @Zia What do want to ask? Explain me

Comment: I use pivot query for class like:
SELECT stu_id, sum(numbers) AS total, branch_id, depart_id, class_id, SUM( IF( subject_id =1, numbers, 0 ) ) AS MAth, SUM( IF( subject_id =2, numbers, 0 ) ) AS Eng,
SUM( IF( subject_id =3, numbers, 0 ) ) AS URDU
FROM marksheet where branch_id = 1 AND depart_id = 1 AND class_id = 1 GROUP BY stu_id ORDER BY total DESC

it is good for display all class result in excel format. can I get rank in this query too?

Comment: @Zia replace this query with inner subquery it will calculate the rank

Comment: @SaharshShah Can you help me ? I have same problem but i also want to consider time stamp. e.g person1 and person 2 have 100 marks but person1 attempted earlier than person 2. Then Person1 and person2 should have rank1 and rank2 respectively